# How to match text against templates in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I have a class that consume an XML file and produce text output based on the input. Both the input and output are rather complex and the output can also include things *not* in the input: e.g. include timestamps and the results from live data that are not controlled by the input - with other words: the class is not a pure input-output transformation.

I would like to test the resulting text output using JUnit. As the produced text can vary in many different ways based on the input, I would like to be able to match specific parts of the output against some sort of template in each test. Each template should allow for some simple text substitutions and also for ranges in the text that should *not* be matched.

The question is whether any such frameworks already exists?

One very low-level possibility would be to use some fancy regular expressions to match the text, but I think these will be a bit too limited for our use as you don't have enough context in regular expressions...

**EDIT**: Two comments:

- One of the functions of the class is the ability to do certain simple types of aggregation of data and calculations (e.g. sums) based on the input. This I would like to test, without testing the rest of the generated text output as well.
- I wish it was possible to make changes to the existing code base, but it is a very large chuck of legacy code that I really don't want to refactor. So introduction of mock services or testing of smaller pieces will not be possible.

Comment: Another possibility is to make the environment of your unit test more controlled by supplying a mock live data feed that never changes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Unfortunately, that is not possible unless I make some massive changes to the code... anyway, I would like to be able to test the various effects of small changes in the input - in which case I don't want to check the complete result, but only some localized effects...

Comment: Maybe it's enough to test if the part you expect is transformed and somewhere in the text. If it's not changing, you can simply use `xml.contains("your string")`. I'm doing that in a similar situation.

Comment: @cringe Unfortunately, the file to test is 1+MB large and the same pattern can be present in many different places... The expression to test for will be rather complicated.

Comment: This is some custom text output that you're working with?  Why not a combination of a standard template system (like Velocity) and a regex, where you render the templates with the provided context from the test as strings and then augment that with regex to indicate the regions which aren't being tested (also generated by the template if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) for writing the unit tests, because this is one of Groovy's strength, see

- [Unit Testing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Unit+Testing)
- [Using JUnit 4 with Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+JUnit+4+with+Groovy)
- [Unit Testing - Groovy](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Unit+Testing)
- [Spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/)

But Groovy is also superb for handling XML, see

- [Prozessing XML](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML)
- [Reading XML using Groovy's XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper)

A little example for summing up some XML attributes:

```groovy
// multiline string, very complex XML content :-)
def input = '''\
<list>
    <summand value='13' time='10:40' text='Compare me!'/>
    <summand value='1' />
    <summand value='4' />
    <summand value='2' />
    <summand value='7' />
</list>'''

// reading XML via XmlSlurper
def list = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

// Prints 13
println list.summand[0].@value

// collect all summand values, prints 27
println list.summand.collect { it.@value.toInteger() }.sum()
```

You can find a good tutorial about testing in the [MEAP Making Java Groovy](http://www.manning.com/kousen/) or look at this [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Improve-Your-Java-with-Groovy).

Groovy has also [template support](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates). But with the XML support it is very easy to compare only certain attributes and not the whole tag content to skip some attributes like the timestamp you mentioned. Therefore you don't need to compare templates. For an example add this source to the skript above:

```groovy
// compare the first summand tag, skipping the time attribute
assert [list.summand[0].@value.toInteger(), list.summand[0].@text] == [13, 'Compare me!']
```

To learn Groovy, I recommend the [Groovy Koans](http://groovykoans.org/). See also [Adding Groovy Tests to a Maven Java Project](https://bowerstudios.com/node/935).

**Update:**
I would not compare the XML against each other, instead I would unit test single values as desribed in my answer. But if you go the complete way I would use the following approach:

- get the XML from your business logic
- remove temporary (not comparable values with Groovy)
- generate a template from GStringTemplateEngine (see link above) without the not comparable values
- compare both XMLs via http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/
  You can find an example on [Updating XML with XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Updating+XML+with+XmlSlurper) the end of the page.

Comment: I award the bounty to you as your answer is the one that is closest to a solution. Note though that the output is not XML in this case, so your answer is not perfect :-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is indicative that you need to be testing at a lower level ? i.e. testing the contributing components rather than the entire output *en masse*. I would hope that you can arrange your code/tests such that you can provide an immutable set of inputs (perhaps using mocking where necessary) and consequently the outputs won't change.

A few high-level tests would be useful (to confirm results integration) and you could perhaps do that by a simple string comparison (just to confirm stuff is being integrated properly) but I think the effort should perhaps be put in at a more granular level.

Otherwise I suspect you may want a diff-like tool, and [this library](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/) looks like it may be useful.

Comment: I wish it was possible, but it is a very large chuck of legacy code that I really don't want to refactor.

Comment: Thanks for the references to java-diff-utils. It might prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have too little info about what you need to achieve, what the output format of the message is, etc. However I assume that since we are talking about testing then you do have a substantial info on the data that you want to test your codebase against.

If the class produces a stable output (i.e. for the same input it produces the same output all the time) then maybe you might want to create some sort of templating for the given set of data that you want to test (for example with **Velocity**). You would apply the data that the input to your class contains to your template as well. Depending on what the output of the tested class is, you could either test if it contains what your template has produced, or (if this is not feasible) use a DIFF tool on what your template has produced.

If your output is a human readable text then maybe indexing it with, say, Lucene and searching for matches could be your solution? If not then still matching a template result or even predefined output with a fuzzy search algorithm might be a viable option.

One question you need to answer is whether refactoring the underlying codebase won't be (especially in the long run) a cheaper task.

Have you also considered testing the behaviour of the underlying code (with **Mockito**) instead of testing its output? I imagine this will be much harder since it is a legacy code you are dealing with, but maybe it is doable? You may also reinforce yourself with the **PowerMock**, which allows for mocking static methods and other magic - usually handy with the legacy code.

Comment: We have considered both refactoring the code and mocking some of the services, but that will be nearly impossible for a number of business related reasons..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to parse the output XML with a tool that transform it into an object tree. Then you can evaluate the object tree instead of the XML string and write your assert statements on only those parts that you are interested in. It also allows you to do tests that are not possible with string tools, e.g. count the number of elements etc.

If you have an XSD of the output, you can use for example XMLBeans or JABX. If you don't have an XSD, you can write an automaton based on SAX or use XPath expressions to pick certain parts of the XML tree.

Comment: I can see from the question that it is not clear that the output is not XML, but plain text :-/

Answer (score -1):

You could use Mockito along with PowerMock to test separated parts of your code, PowerMock lets you do anything you like including replacing new instance creation with mock objects, mocking/replacing static, private methods and classes, in short, everything.  This combination should prove powerful enough to test separate parts of the code without having to test the whole thing.

I don't think you can call something Unit test when you run a 1mb file through an uncontrolled flow with many different parts, you can't really know what happens and where it happened when something breaks.